# Updating Paperclip path file names from on server to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a paperclip instance that I am migrating my files to a different area. Originally the files were stored on my server and just given a filename based on the id of the record created and the original id. Now I'm moving them to s3 and want to update the filenames to work appropriately. I setup my paperclip config like so:

```
:path => ":class/:attachment/:hash-:style.:extension",
    :url => ":s3_domain_url",
    :hash_secret => SECRET,
    :hash_data => ":class/:attachment/:id/:updated_at"
```

I updated the original records filenames for my files to be unique and moved them over to my s3 instance. Unfortunately now I am unable to pull down the files from s3 and I think it is because paperclip is using the wrong path for the filenames. One that is based off the path default that is now set using my config file. I want to be able to update my files file_name field so that the path is correct for the new files and I am able to download them appropriately. Is there a way to call paperclips hashing function based on my secret and hash_data directly so I can update those file_name fields and be able to pull those records now? Everything that has been uploaded since the move from my original servers seems to work appropriately.

Comment: Are you looking for this https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Hashing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have a model *User* with an attachment named *profile_pic*;

Go into the rails console eg. `rails c` and then get an object for the model you have the attachment on, eg. `u = User.find(100)`.

Now type `u.profile_pic.url` to get the url or `u.profile_pic_file_name` to get the filename.

To see the effect of other options (for example your old options) you can do;

```
p = u.profile_pic # gets the paperclip attachment for profile_pic
puts p.url # gets the current url
p.options.merge!(url: '/blah/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename')
puts p.url # now shows url with the new options
```

Similarly `p.path` will show the local file path with whatever options you pick.

Long story short, something like;

```
User.where('created_at < some_date').map do |x| 
  "#{x.id} #{x.profile_pic_file_name} #{x.profile_pic.path}" 
end
```

should give you what you want :)

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question - you can rename files on s3, yes.

Comment: ...how? the aws-sdk has only read-only items on objects you manipulate within s3 buckets. I posted another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550527/rename-object-in-s3-using-ruby) with more info